# Due date is close warning

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how to make a warning when its missing 10 days to due date in laravel and php using for  (data_saida is my due date)

```
 @for ($i = Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10); $i < $client->data_saida; $i--)
                     <div class="container-light">
                        <div class="lights"></div>
                        <div class="lights yellow"></div>
                        <div class="lights"></div>
                    </div>
                     @endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decrement must be

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(1)
```

or

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(1)
```

like

```
@for ($i = Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10); $i < $client->data_saida; $i->addDays(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon `diffInDays()` function (assuming your $data_saida is a Carbon object)

```
@if($data_saida->diffInDays($now) > 10)
    // Display Warning DIV
@endif
```